# Center a row element in a table

Tags: html

I have an html table of width 222px

Inside in I have a single row with width defined as 160px.

Inside this row, there is a single column having same width as that
of the row.

My question is, how to align this row to the center of the table.

I have tried align="center"and style="float:center;" but these work only
on the contained text.

Comment: Throw the table away. 1x1 tables make no sense. Tables with rows that aren't as wide as the table make no sense. Use appropriate markup.

Comment: I am using the 1x1 table as these tables are generated from the query and for each resultset i have different color for the table, it's contained row and it's contained column.

Comment: tr does not have a css width property.  It is always as wide as the table itself.

Comment: +1 for thinking outside the box and trying `style="float:center"`. Most preople wouldn't think of trying that, because they would assume it wouldn't do anything. That said, what are you trying to achieve? Why are you convinced you need a table?

Comment: The reason for using table is that I want to have 3 different coloured boxes, one inside another.

Comment: I repeat the question, is there "any" way to do this? Is not, I will just throw away the table and use div etc. Just for my reference I want to know if this is possible at all.

Comment: Have you tried using these css properties: `outline` and `border` in conjunction with `margin` of the td?

Comment: If all you want is 3 different colored borders, then maybe `outline` can help you achieve this.

Comment: End of the discussion, I also agree with Quentin. It's just that I wanted to know how to achieve it using tables. Thanks Lister for the working solution.

Comment: But if all you want is nested coloured boxes (maybe in the future some time), you only need _one_ element, and some clever CSS. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/62QHG/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But if you really, really must use a table, here's how to style it:

```
.resultset {
  width:222px; border:1px solid;
  border-collapse:separate; border-spacing:30px 2px;
}
.resultset td {
  border:1px solid;
}
```

Where the 30px in the border-spacing is half the horizontal difference between the table width and the cell width.

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zj48R/1/).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this like that

```
 <table width="222px" align="center">
 <td width="31px"></td>
 <td width="160px">test</td>
 <td width="31px"></td>
 </table>
```

test here : http://www.webmasterorbit.com/wysiwyg-html-tester.html

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Quentin. There is no point having a 1x1 table.

Try with the following.

```
<div style="margin: 0px auto; position: relative; width: 222px;">
....your content
</div>
```

You might want to create a CSS class for the div. I personally don't like having inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

You must use this

```
<td align = 'center'>Blah blah</td>
```

using this wont work

```
<tr align = 'center'></tr>
```

Comment: I need to align the <tr> within the table. Please see Lister's answer.